# How do you set a event listener/handler if someone types in the address bar?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-router-dom

I am trying to load a template in a component in the `useEffect` hook if someone types in the address bar. `e.g http://localhost:3000/product/2`

Right now I get an infinite loop:

```
useEffect(() => {
  function loadTemplate() {
    handleGetProductModalTemplate(<ProductModalTemplate />);
  }

  if (
    document.readyState === 'complete' &&
    location.pathname == `/product/${id + ''}`
  ) {
    loadTemplate();
  } else {
    window.addEventListener('load', loadTemplate);
  }
   
  return () => document.removeEventListener('load', loadTemplate);
}, [handleGetProductModalTemplate, id, location.pathname]);
```

**UPDATE**
This is the full component:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useCallback } from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import cx from 'classnames';

import Button from '../Button';
import LinkButton from '../LinkButton';

import Quantity from '../Quantity';
import { useParams } from 'react-router-dom';

import { getImage } from '../../utils/images';
import imageTypes from '../../constants/imageTypes';

import styles from './Product.module.scss';
import modal from '../Modal/Modal.module.scss';
import { withRouter, useLocation, useHistory } from 'react-router-dom';

const Product = ({
  products,
  className,
  count = 1,
  getProductModalTemplate,
  history,
  location,
  images,
  isAdded,
  isFeatured,
  onClick,
  onDecrement,
  onIncrement,
  price,
  title,
  id
}) => {
 

  const handleGetProductModalTemplate = useCallback(template => {
    getProductModalTemplate(template);
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    return history.listen(location => {
      console.log('location ', location);
      console.log(`You changed the page to: ${location.pathname}`);
    });
  }, [history]);


  useEffect(() => {
    function loadTemplate() {
      handleGetProductModalTemplate(<ProductModalTemplate />);
    }


    if (
      document.readyState === 'complete' &&
      location.pathname == `/product/${id + ''}`
    ) {
      loadTemplate();
    } else {
      window.addEventListener('load', loadTemplate);
    }
    // } else {
    //   window.addEventListener('load', loadTemplate);
    return () => document.removeEventListener('load', loadTemplate);
  }, [handleGetProductModalTemplate, id, location.pathname]);

  const ProductModalTemplate = ({ routeID }) => {
    const [images, setImages] = useState([]);
    const [srcImage, setSrcImage] = useState(imageSrc);

    useEffect(() => {

      if (products != undefined) {
        products.map(product => {
          if (product.id === id || product.id == routeID) {
            product.images.map((imageArray, i, arr) => {
              if (imageArray.type.includes('Square')) {
                setImages(images => {
                  let image = (
                    <img
                      key={imageArray.type}
                      className={modal.imageThumbs}
                      src={arr[i].src}
                      alt={product.title}
                      data-description={product.description}
                      data-id={product.id}
                      onClick={() => {
                        console.log('click');
                        setSrcImage(() => arr[i].src);
                        return false;
                      }}
                    />
                  );

                  return [...images, image];
                });
              }
            });
          }
        });
      }
    }, [routeID]);
    return (
      <>
        <div className={modal.modalTemplate}>
          <header className={modal.header}>
            <h2 className={modal.title}>{title}</h2>
            <span className={modal.price}>${finalPrice}</span>
          </header>
          <img className={modal.product} src={srcImage} alt={title} />
          <div className={modal.imageThumbContainer}>
            {images.map(image => image)}
          </div>
          <div className={modal.description}>
            <span className={modal.descriptionTitle}>
              <strong>DESCRIPTION</strong>
            </span>
            <br />
            {images[0] != undefined
              ? images[0].props['data-description']
              : null}
          </div>
         
        </div>
      </>
    );
  };

  return (
    <>
      <div className={productClasses}>
        <LinkButton
          to={`/product/${id}`}
          onClick={() =>
            handleGetProductModalTemplate(<ProductModalTemplate />)
          }
        >
          <img className={styles.image} src={imageSrc} alt={title} />
        </LinkButton>
        <div className={styles.details}>
          <div className={styles.text}>
            <LinkButton
              to={`/product/${id}`}
              onClick={() =>
                handleGetProductModalTemplate(<ProductModalTemplate />)
              }
            >
              <h2 className={styles.title}>{title}</h2>{' '}
            </LinkButton>

            <span className={styles.price}>${finalPrice}</span>
          </div>
          {isInCart ? (
            <Quantity
              onIncrement={onIncrement}
              onDecrement={onDecrement}
              count={count}
            />
          ) : (
            <Button
              className={styles.addButton}
              disabled={isAdded}
              onClick={onClick}
            >
              {isAdded ? 'Added' : 'Add to Bag'}
            </Button>
          )}
        </div>
      </div>
    </>
  );
};



export default withRouter(Product);
```

**Update #2**

App component:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { Switch, Route, useLocation, withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';

import useAppContext, { providerPropTypes } from './hooks/useAppContext';
import AppContext from './contexts/AppContext';
import Modal from './components/Modal';
import ProductLanding from './pages/ProductLanding';
import Cart from './pages/Cart';

function App() {
  const appContextValue = useAppContext();
  let location = useLocation();

  const [productModalTemplate, getProductModalTemplate] = useState(null);

  const [previousLocation, setPreviousLocation] = useState(location);

  const isModal = previousLocation.pathname == location.pathname;

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log('productModalTemplate', productModalTemplate);
    if (!(location.state && location.state.product)) {
      setPreviousLocation(location);
    }
  }, [isModal, location, productModalTemplate]);

  return (
    <AppContext.Provider value={appContextValue}>
      <ProductLanding getProductModalTemplate={getProductModalTemplate} />
      <Switch location={isModal ? previousLocation : location}>
        <Route path="/cart">
          <Cart />
        </Route>
      </Switch>

      <Route exact path="/product/:id">
        <Modal
          modalTemplate={
            productModalTemplate != null ? (
              productModalTemplate
            ) : (
              <div>Nothing</div>
            )
          }
          isModal={isModal}
        />
      </Route>
    </AppContext.Provider>
  );
}

AppContext.Provider.propTypes = providerPropTypes;

export default withRouter(App);
```

Essentially I am prop drilling that function to add the template till it finally gets to the `<Product/>` component.

Comment: It's unclear if you're asking if a webpage can listen for changes to the address bar *while* someone is typing into it, or if you just need to handle when the URL updates. Can you clarify?

Comment: Can this not be solved with routing? when the route matches, load the template? see here: https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Hooks for some hooks that seem relevant.

Comment: I'd like to listen if someone types `http://localhost:3000/product/2` and hits enter so I can load that template. RIght now I have it wired to the product image or title.

Comment: @Squiggs. Thanks! I thought of that, but wouldn't it fire once the url would propagate from clicking the link? Thereby firing twice?

Comment: Ok, so you want to handle when the URL/routing path changes. You can handle this with the [useLocation](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Hooks/uselocation) or `location` route prop and check the `pathname`. You could also use the [useRouteMatch](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Hooks/useroutematch) hook similarly.

Comment: @DrewReese I thought of that, but wouldn't that be triggered when clicking the Link tag? Making two requests

Comment: What link tag? Is there more relevant code for your question? https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example Just FYI, the react hooks have nothing to do with any `Link` components a user is clicking on. If the code is render looping then somehow the effect is updating one of its dependencies. What is `handleGetProductModalTemplate` and what does it do?

Comment: I updated my code!

Comment: How is `Product` being rendered? I suspect that since `handleGetProductModalTemplate` calls the `getProductModalTemplate` prop that you've coded your app/routing in such a way to cause unintentional remounting. Can you also explain what `handleGetProductModalTemplate(<ProductModalTemplate />)` is doing? This seems a code smell to me, especially if you are storing it in state somewhere.

Comment: @DrewReese I added the App component above. Essentially I'm prop drilling `getProductModalTemplate ` for the `Product` component.

`handleGetProductModalTemplate` is a handler in the `Product` component which is assigned to onClick on the image and title of the product. I did it this way because all the data goes through/to the product anyway.

Answer (score 1):

I think I see the issue. `handleGetProductModalTemplate` is a dependency of the `useEffect` but it's redeclared each render cycle since the `useCallback` hook is missing a dependency array.

```
const handleGetProductModalTemplate = useCallback(template => {
  getProductModalTemplate(template);
});

useEffect(() => {
  function loadTemplate() {
    handleGetProductModalTemplate(<ProductModalTemplate />);
  }

  if (
    document.readyState === 'complete' &&
    location.pathname == `/product/${id + ''}`
  ) {
    loadTemplate();
  } else {
    window.addEventListener('load', loadTemplate);
  }
  return () => document.removeEventListener('load', loadTemplate);
}, [handleGetProductModalTemplate, id, location.pathname]);
```

If `getProductModalTemplate` is a prop passed in and if invoking it triggers `Products` to rerender, then the `useEffect` hook callback will be invoked again, which triggers a rerender.... looping indefinitely.

The solution is to add a dependency array to the `useCallback`.

```
const handleGetProductModalTemplate = useCallback(template => {
  getProductModalTemplate(template);
}, []);
```

Since `getProductModalTemplate` is a state updater function it is guaranteed to be a [stable reference](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usestate).

> **Note**
>
> React guarantees that `setState` function identity is stable and won’t
> change on re-renders. This is why it’s safe to omit from the `useEffect`
> or `useCallback` dependency list.

If the linter does complain about it though, it should be safe to add to the dependency array.

```
const handleGetProductModalTemplate = useCallback(template => {
  getProductModalTemplate(template);
}, [getProductModalTemplate]);
```

#### Suggestion

It's an anti-pattern in React to store React components into state, store "data" instead. Instead of passing a JSX literal in the callback back out to the parent you should pass back a reference to the `ProductModalTemplate` component and instantiate it in the parent component when rendering.

```
handleGetProductModalTemplate(ProductModalTemplate);
```

Parent:

```
const [ProductModalTemplate, getProductModalTemplate] = useState(null);

...

<Route exact path="/product/:id">
  <Modal
    modalTemplate={
      ProductModalTemplate != null ? (
        <ProductModalTemplate />
      ) : (
        <div>Nothing</div>
      )
    }
    isModal={isModal}
  />
</Route>
```

Comment: Hey thank you for this explanation. I really appreciate it!I’m actually going to pick up my four-year-old daughter right now so I can’t test it. Can I ask you another question? I was given this layout before hand. And I did think myself I was kind of painting myself into a corner, the way I architected it’s so far. But because the way they laid it out I felt like that was the best thing to do...

Comment: @AntonioPavicevac-Ortiz Sure, you ask me another question.

Comment: @AntonioPavicevac-Ortiz Had you an opportunity to test this solution? And you mentioned having an additional question.

Comment: Hi Drew, It seemed to work for a moment but then I started getting this error `Error: Should have a queue. This is likely a bug in React. Please file an issue.
` Googling it indeed yield folks having to open a issue about it.